# What would happen to the Internet in the case of a war between major powers?

Tags: security, internet

In the case of [Operation Enduring Freedom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Enduring_Freedom) and [Iraq Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iraq_war) the Internet suffered minor hits from those minor powers isolation or absense.

But what would happen if major powers start a war? A [Netsplit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netsplit)? Would a major power isolate himself from the world as a security measure against eletronic attacks? If yes, it would be a physical disconnection or a logical one?

Comment: i think this is very interesing question, wiki form would be probably better - but still - i hardly can understand people voting to close it.

Comment: You might start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_warfare  in particular, get the book by Winn Schwartau.  Highly informative about what is actually possible

Comment: community wiki now

Comment: This should not have been closed.  There is a current bill in the US Senate that talks about this very issue, S.773: http://www.opencongress.org/bill/111-s773/show

Comment: Not saying it's an irrelevant topic, just doesn't fit the purpose of this site.

Comment: Agreed, it's more of a general discussion topic than a question.

Answer (score 3):

The real world is less glamourous than a Tom Clancy novel. :)

Critical services are not on the internet in the first place and it is more useful as an information channel/propoganda tool than it is a risk of electronic attack.

I very much doubt that any major power would cut themselves off from the rest of the world.  More likely is a great firewall like China already have in place and Iran used during recent troubles filtering the ideas that it's people are exposed to from the rest of the world and its perceived enemies.

Comment: Lots of companies have lots of critical services on the internet these days, be it VOIP or backup, or what have you.

Comment: You might want to redefine critical.  It's not just about whether you can hack the DoD.  Most large businesses are completely accessible from the internet.  Disrupting your enemies business is a key part to information warfare.

Comment: But how many of those companies are providing vital services? At a time of war people's priorities change to survival. Basics of food, water and energy.  No one is going to be worrying about backup or VOIP.

Comment: Financial services rely heavily on telecommunications.